# Differing outputs of the commands "ls .*" and "ls *."

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

The command

```
    ls .*
```

when run gives as output the following :

- All the files in the current directory starting with a . (hidden files)
- All the files in the hidden directories present in the current directory
- All the files in the current directory
- All the files in the parent directory

Why does the command

```
    ls *.
```

not display :

- All the files in the current directory
- All the files in the parent directory

Reason I am thinking so is : The regular expression *. should match both . and ..  So ls should be run on both and thus the output which I am expecting should be displayed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `*` doesn't match files starting with a `.` by default. Consider the following directory:

```
$ ls -la 
total 8404
drwxrwxrwx   2 terdon terdon 8105984 Dec 31 13:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 153 terdon terdon  491520 Dec 30 22:32 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon       0 Dec 31 13:14 .dotfile
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon       0 Dec 31 13:14 file1
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon       0 Dec 31 13:14 file2
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon       0 Dec 31 13:14 file3.
```

Let's see what each of the globs you used expands to:

```
$ echo .*
. .. .dotfile

$ echo *.
file3.

$ echo *
file1 file2 file3.
```

As you can see, the `*` does not include files or directories starting with `.` so both `./` and `../` are ignored. The same thing happens with your `ls` example. In `bash`, you can change this with the `dotglob` parameter, which will cause `*` to expand to dotfiles as well (but not to `.` or `..`, those are still ignored):

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo *
.dotfile
```

Other shells behave differently. For example `zsh` also ignores the `.` and `..` when using `.*`:

```
% echo .*
.dotfile
```

Comment: @8bittree oh wow, yes indeed I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The rule for filename expansion have a special case for `.` as the first character in a filename: it must be explicitly matched (i.e. the pattern must contain a starting `.`, or `.` after a `/`). Otherwise these files are not candidates.

This is why your first version does pick up filenames that start with `.`, but the second doesn't. `*` doesn't match `.` as the first character of a filename.

[POSIX Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13) describes it as:

> If a filename begins with a period ( '.' ), the period shall be explicitly matched by using a period as the first character of the pattern or immediately following a slash character. The leading period shall not be matched by:
>
> - The asterisk or question-mark special characters
> - A bracket expression containing a non-matching list, such as "[!a]", a range expression, such as "[%-0]", or a character class expression, such as "[[:punct:]]"
>
> It is unspecified whether an explicit period in a bracket expression matching list, such as "[.abc]", can match a leading period in a filename.

Your shell might have options to change this behavior. Bash has this for instance ([Filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)):

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set. When matching a file name, the slash character must always be matched explicitly. In other cases, the ‘.’ character is not treated specially.

---

Note that these are **not** regular expressions. `.*` as a regex would match anything at all (including nothing). `*.` would be ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this really has nothing to do with `ls`. The shell you are using does globbing (more generally, substitutions). The `*` or `.*` you give is expanded (*globbed*) by the shell to all object names matching `*` (everything that doesn't start `.`, a `.` at the beginning is a special case here) or `.*` (everything whose name starts `.`). That list is handed to `ls` (or whatever hapless command is being called), and that one now is in charge. Your commands never learn if they were invoked with `*` or if you painstakingly wrote out all names.

Rationale is that it simplifies hundreds (literally) of commands, and moreover makes their "argument handling" uniform (by not doing it at all ;-). Downside is that you can't say e.g. `mv *.txt *.bak` as you'd like to move all `.txt` files to `.bak` with the same name. Oh, well.